# How to use Multiple between statement in single SQL statement to get different Range Values

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my parts Table

```
---------+---------+----------------+--------------+
| part_id | part_no | purchase_price | retail_price |
+---------+---------+----------------+--------------+
|       1 |      11 |            600 |          650 |
|       2 |      12 |            200 |          260 |
|       3 |      13 |            200 |          280 |
|       4 |      14 |            520 |          600 |
|       5 |      15 |            150 |          180 |
|       6 |      16 |            160 |          185 |
|       7 |      17 |            180 |          200 |
|       8 |      18 |            600 |          710 |
|       9 |      19 |            500 |          580 |
|      10 |      20 |            780 |          850 |
|      11 |      21 |            145 |          200 |
|      12 |      22 |           6200 |         6500 |
|      13 |      23 |           1030 |         1100 |
|      14 |      24 |            720 |          800 |
|      15 |      25 |            400 |          600 |
|      16 |      26 |           1400 |         1600 |
|      17 |      27 |            800 |         1000 |
|      18 |      28 |             90 |          100 |
|      19 |      29 |           1500 |         1600 |
|      20 |      30 |           2000 |         2100 |
+---------+---------+----------------+--------------+
```

How can i get output as below

```
+---------+--------------+----------------+------------------------------+
| part_id | retail_price(between 100-600) |retail_price(between 800-2400)|
+---------+--------------+----------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: And what statistic do you want - an average price , a count of those falling into these bands or something else?

Comment: Please provide output based on the given input and clarify your logic.

Comment: You can't have retail_price between 100 -600 and between 800-2400 for the same part simultaneously.

Comment: Part_id makes no sense in this result

Comment: Can you post a sample sets of result? Something like, querying for parts with these criteria should provide this result. At the moment its hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "Or" if you want to get the two ranges Like below

```
select part_id , part_no , purchase_price , retail_price from parts
where (purchase_price between 100 and 600) or (retail_price between 800 and 2400 )
```

but if you want the intersections between the two ranges use " and "

```
select part_id , part_no , purchase_price , retail_price from parts
where (purchase_price between 100 and 600) and (retail_price between 800 and 2400 )
```

Answer (score -1):

you may try it

```
SELECT part_id , retail_price FROM parts WHERE retail_price NOT BETWEEN 600 AND 800;
```